# MYSQL LEFT JOIN 3 tables include NULL sets

Tags: mysql, left-join

Tried to 'reverse engineer' other SO users questions/answers to my question but couldn't. JOINS still elude me.

I have three tables: race (a list of all races), result (results for each race), driver (driver information). Not all drivers have raced in all races at a specific track.

race table

```
| race_id   | track_id   | year   | complete |
+-----------+------------+--------+----------+
| 1         | 1          | 2006   | 1        |
| ...       | ...        | ...    | ...      |
| 21        | 1          | 2007   | 1        |
| ...       | ...        | ...    | ...      |
| 135       | 1          | 2008   | 1        |
| ...       | ...        | ...    | ...      |
| 215       | 1          | 2009   | 1        |
| ...       | ...        | ...    | ...      |
| 292       | 1          | 2010   | 1        |
| ...       | ...        | ...    |...       |
| 351       | 1          | 2011   | 0        |
+-----------+------------+--------+----------+
```

result table

```
| race_id | driver_id | finish |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 135     | 1         | 15     |
| ...     | ...       | ...    |
| 292     | 1         | 6      |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

driver table

```
| driver_id | name       |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | Joe Driver |
+-----------+------------+
```

I want a result set that shows:

```
| name       | race_id |  year  | finish |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| Joe Driver | 21      | 2007   | NULL   |
| Joe Driver | 135     | 2008   | 15     |
| Joe Driver | 215     | 2009   | NULL   |
| Joe Driver | 292     | 2010   | 6      |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Joe Driver only raced in 2 of the 4 races that were at track_id = 1, after 2006 and only includes races that are complete (1)

This is my current query:

```
SELECT driver.driver, race.id, race.year, result.finish
FROM race
LEFT JOIN result ON race.id = result.race_id
LEFT JOIN driver ON result.driver_id = driver.driver_id
WHERE race.track_id = 1
AND race.year > 2006
AND race.complete = 1
AND driver.driver_id = 1
ORDER BY race.id ASC
```

The result I get only shows the races the driver was in:

```
| name       | race_id |  year  | finish |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| Joe Driver | 135     | 2008   | 15     |
| Joe Driver | 292     | 2010   | 6      |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking a simple rule to JOINS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  driver.driver, race.id, race.year, result.finish
FROM    race
CROSS JOIN
        driver
LEFT JOIN
        result
ON      result.race_id = race.id
        AND result.driver_id = driver.driver_id
WHERE   race.track_id = 1
        AND race.year > 2006
        AND race.complete = 1
        AND driver.driver_id = 1
ORDER BY
        race.id ASC
```

Comment: Quassnoi: Thanks! That does the trick exactly. Looks like CROSS JOIN is the key. I'd like to ask an intelligent question about how the CROSS JOIN and the subsequent LEFT JOIN makes all the other drivers be filtered out of the query...but I can't. Suggestions on the best resource to learn more about JOINS?

Comment: @darrenfauth: read documentation for the starters and my site, http://explainextended.com, for more advanced topics :)

Comment: And it's `driver.driver_id = 1` in the `WHERE` clause that filters out the other drivers, not the joins. Remove `driver.driver_id = 1` and you will see all drivers.